# How to read int from file after specific word in Java

Tags: java, apache, jsp, servlets

Im trying to read an int that will be after a specific word. I tried doing it with delimiters and scanner but can't seem to get the int to the variable I want. Any tips or fixes for this code?

This is what I tried:

```
public void readFromFile(String resultOrNot, String fileName) {

nameOfFile = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Matrices/WEB-INF/MatrixData/";
workMe = fileName;

try {

Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile + workMe));
readFile.useDelimiter("Rows: ");

while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
    stringRow = readFile.next();

}
setRow1VIAString(stringRow);

readFile.useDelimiter("Columns: ");

while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
    stringCol = readFile.next();

}
setColumn1VIAString(stringCol);

readFile.useDelimiter("Method used: ");
while(readFile.hasNext()) {
    operationName = readFile.next();
}


readFile.useDelimiter("\n");
for(int i = 0; i < row1 || readFile.hasNextDouble(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < column1; j++)
        matrix1[i][j] = readFile.nextDouble();

readFile.close();



workMe = workMe.replace("MAIN", "SECOND");
readFile = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile + workMe));
readFile.useDelimiter("Rows: ");

while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
    stringRow = readFile.next();

}
setRow2VIAString(stringRow);

readFile.useDelimiter("Columns: ");

while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
    stringCol = readFile.next();

}
setColumn2VIAString(stringCol);

readFile.useDelimiter("\n");
for(int i = 0; i < row1 || readFile.hasNextDouble(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < column1; j++)
        matrix1[i][j] = readFile.nextDouble();

readFile.close();

if("giveMeResult".equals(resultOrNot)) {

workMe = workMe.replace("SECOND", "RESULT");
readFile = new Scanner(new File(nameOfFile + workMe));
readFile.useDelimiter("Rows: ");

while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
    stringRow = readFile.next();

}
setRow3VIAString(stringRow);

readFile.useDelimiter("Columns: ");

while(readFile.hasNextInt()) {
    stringCol = readFile.next();

}
setColumn3VIAString(stringCol);

readFile.useDelimiter("\n");
for(int i = 0; i < row3 || readFile.hasNextDouble(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < column3; j++)
        matrix1[i][j] = readFile.nextDouble();

}




} catch(IOException ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
matrixcalculator.MatrixCalculator.setRow1VIAString(MatrixCalculator.java:171)
matrixcalculator.MatrixCalculator.readFromFile(MatrixCalculator.java:728)
org.apache.jsp.choosing_jsp._jspService(choosing_jsp.java:84)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
setRow1VIAString(stringRow);
```

you are assuming that stringRow has a value read from the file.

What if this condition is never true?

```
while(readFile.hasNextInt())
```

stringRow would be null and hence the error.

This is my best guess, as I can't know what is in your file or the full context of the source.

EDIT:
Try

```
readFile.useDelimiter("\\s*Rows:\\s*");
```

Or since you know the exact format, this might work too

```
readFile.findInLine("Rows: (\\d+)");
MatchResult result = readFile.match();
for (int i=1; i<=result.groupCount(); i++)
    System.out.println(result.group(i));
```

Comment: The thing is that stringRow must get from the file a specific number. Example in the file there will be a line with the next statement Rows: 3 
I need to get the number 3 into stringRow so that then the function setRow1VIAString(stringRow) executes a code that parses that argument into a int to assign to a different variable. Also the while(readFile.hasNextInt()) is the problem, it nevers executes because I doesnt find the number.

Comment: Try printing stringRow before you call setRow1VIAString(stringRow); You will see that stringRow is null.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, stringRow is null. I can't get it to get the number from the file. It just skips.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71212/discussion-between-kjp-and-silvestrini).

Comment: Manage to make it work through the other errors I got after your help. Thanks!